# Is there any method to solve this output problem or to initialize i

Tags: java, c++, output

These are two of the same code, the first one is in C++, and the other is in Java. The C++ code is compiling successfully, while the Java code gives an error:

> last is not initialized

but at the end, the value of `i` will be the `last`. But it is throwing an error, please help me to figure it out.

C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int last;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]; 
        last = i;
    }
    cout<<last;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1234565
```

Java code:

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int last;
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
           System.out.print(arr[i]);
           last = i;
        }
        System.out.print(last);
        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Main.java:19: error: variable last might not have been initialized
        System.out.print(last);
                         ^
1 error
```

Comment: You could just initialize it. Good practice in C+ as well.

Comment: It’s a compile error. The compiler isn’t smart enough to know last always gets a value. Initialize last to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you didn't initialise the variable first. Initializing them is setting them equal to a value:

```
int a;        // This is a declaration
a = 0;        // This is an initialization
int b = 1;    // This is a declaration and initialization
```

Please note, Java primitives have default values but as one user commented below

**Their default value is zero when declared as class members. Local variables don't have default values**

Try the following:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int last = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
        last = i;
    }
    System.out.print(last);
}
```